# Need help scraping data off of 3rd party dynamic website (lolalytics.com)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

So for example I'm trying to scrape specific data such as delta's on pages like: https://lolalytics.com/lol/nautilus/build/.

I know the xpath of the elements that I need such as : `//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[11]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]`

But whenever I call for them through python it just returns an empty list.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

headers = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
      }
url = "https://lolalytics.com/lol/olaf/build/?tier=platinum&patch=13.3"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


tree = html.fromstring(page.content) 
xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/text()[1]'
stat = tree.xpath(xpath)
print([j.text for j in stat])
```

This is the example of one of the codes I run.

Another question is how to have python scroll through specific scrollers such as this one for example?  [image]

Comment: Have you verified that `page.content` contains what you think it should?

Comment: _"how to have python scroll through specific scrollers"_ - the way you are currently doing this - not at all. You are _only_ making an HTTP request here, so there _isn't_ anything that could be "scrolled" anywhere. You will need to use a _headless browser_ if you want to do your scraping while also performing "client-side" actions on the target page ...

Comment: You don't need to scrape the whole site if you check the HTML code you will see in the script section a precache JSON object which has all the information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working the way you try it. Modern Websites are getting their dynamic Data for example via ajax of a backend. So the pure `.html` file has no information About Winrate, etc. It is static. The div's are loaded empty and are getting filled by a js script.

Check the js-section and try to find the code where the data is fetched and parsed into the div's.

Good luck!